# MUI - как на одной странице вывести две разные иконки

Tags: mui

Использую MUI. Пытаюсь разместить на одной странице несколько иконок svg.

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon1 } from '../../img/svg/Icon1.svg'
import { ReactComponent as Icon2 } from '../../img/svg/Icon2.svg'
.......

<SvgIcon component={Icon1} inheritViewBox />
<SvgIcon component={Icon2} inheritViewBox />
```

В результате везде отображается иконка "Icon1". Если две последние строки поменять местами - везде будет отображаться "Icon2"!!!

Как мне отобразить две разные иконки? Спасибо.

Пробовал обновлять и переустанавливать библиотеки.

Comment: При чём здесь [MUI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUI) ?

Comment: В своем проекте на React использую данную библиотеку. Действую, согласно иструкции - https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#svgicon

Comment: тогда нужно дополнить вопрос соответствующими метками.